# regex to find css file that have an inlined background-image inside a media query

Tags: css, regex

I need to find css files that have an inlined base64 background-image property within a media query (example is copied below).  I only need to detect that the file has such text, I don't need to operate on it.  My regex skills are minimal and I have not found one that works.  Basically need to detect @media, skip any number of chars, detect open curly brace, skip any number of characters, detect 'base64', detect closing curly brace.  I am using Java.

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .foo { height: 100% }
  .xdsoft_next{
    background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing due to your lack of examples of what you have tried and not specifying what tool you use (dialects differ across tools), but I believe a common frustration for newbies to regex is due to the fact that the "0 or more any characters" pattern, `.*` does not match across newlines/line breaks. One way to get around this problem is to match "all whitespace and all non-whitespace characters": `[\s\S]*`. This works because whitespace includes newline characters, and the two sets are complementary.

(You also need to escape curly braces. Hopefully this is obvious...)

So, this pattern should do what you want: `\@media [\s\S]*\{[\s\S]*base64[\s\S]*\}`

Comment: Thank you for the help.  What I ended up doing was using a full css parser so I could manipulate the abstract syntax tree. You are right, I did not provide enough info in my question, I will fix that.